# Maven Tests Does Not Run Cucumber Scenarios with Spring Boot 2.2 and JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, junit5

I am trying JUnit 5 and Cucumber at Spring Boot 2.2.6 and will need both BDD scenarios and unit tests at my application. I have created a dummy ping controller corresponding feature file which are OK.

Cucumber tests are not called when I run `mvn clean test`. Only JUnit test is called. However, I can run Cucumber scenarios from Intellij GUI when click on the `Run Test` button for `CucumberTest.java`.

Here are my classes:

`DummyApplicationTests.java:`

```
package com.a.dummy;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DummyApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

`CucumberTest.java:`

```
package com.a.dummy.bdd;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features")
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

`CucumberSpringContextConfiguration.java:`

```
package com.a.dummy.bdd;

import com.a.dummy.DummyApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DummyApplication.class)
public abstract class CucumberSpringContextConfiguration {

}
```

`PingTest.java:`

```
package com.a.dummy.bdd.steps;

import com.a.dummy.bdd.CucumberSpringContextConfiguration;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class PingTest extends CucumberSpringContextConfiguration {

    @When("^the client calls /ping")
    public void the_client_issues_GET_ping() {
        ...
    }

    @Then("^the client receives status code of (\\d+)$")
    public void the_client_receives_status_code_of(int statusCode) {
        ...
    }

    @And("^the client receives ping response")
    public void the_client_receives_ping_response_body() {
       ...
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing `junit-vintage` somehow. Are regular JUnit 4 tests still executed?

Comment: You're also mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5  in your `DummyApplicationTests`

Comment: I've excluded vintage as follows: 
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`

I don't have JUnit 4 tests. Only JUnit 5 tests are executed. Could you elaborate what is mixed?

Comment: I've removed `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` but still same.

Comment: Seems that JUnit 5 support is not integrated and I had to include junit-vintege. RunWith is a Junit 4 annotation.

Comment: You can use the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine if you want to use JUnit 5. But the tooling support leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JUnit 5 support has not yet integrated and I had to include junit-vintage due to RunWith is a Junit 4 annotation.

Answer (score 7):

If you just upgraded to Spring 2.4.0 and maven doesn't run you integration tests, it's because:

> Cucumber is based on JUnit 4. If you’re using JUnit 5, remember to
> include junit-vintage-engine dependency, as well. For more
> information, please refer to JUnit 5 documentation.
> [Cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/)

From [Spring Boot 2.4.0 reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) you can fix it as follows:

> If you have tests that use JUnit 4, JUnit 5’s vintage engine can be
> used to run them. To use the vintage engine, add a dependency on
> junit-vintage-engine, as shown in the following example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2021 answer could be to add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml file as this allows Cucumber to work with Junit 5. See also https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/README.md for more ideas.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue with Spring boot 2.4.0 because it only supports JUnit 5, and seems like Cucumber only integrates with JUnit 4 (RunWith). Go back to Spring boot 2.3.6 (which has backwards compatibility with JUnit 4) solved the issue.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing

> 26.1. Test Scope Dependencies The spring-boot-starter-test “Starter” (in the test scope) contains the following provided libraries:
>
> JUnit 5 (including the vintage engine for backward compatibility with
> JUnit 4): The de-facto standard for unit testing Java applications.

Comment: Another option is to add "junit-vintage-engine" dependency. From the docs: "If you have tests that use JUnit 4, JUnit 5’s vintage engine can be used to run them. To use the vintage engine, add a dependency on junit-vintage-engine." Link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing