# I am using springboot framework, My test runner file is not running, but not showing any errors

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

```
I am using sprintboot framework, I am stuck with test runner file, runner file is not executing the tests.    
POM.xml -   
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
< project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   
< modelVersion>4.0.0< /modelVersion>         
    < parent >         
        < groupId>org.springframework.boot< /groupId>            
        < artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent< /artifactId>          
        < version>2.5.6< /version>             
        < relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    < /parent>              
    < groupId>com.xx.xx< /groupId>             
    < artifactId>srt3.automation< /artifactId>         
    < version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT< /version>           
    < name>srt3.automation< /name>           
    < description>SRT 3.0 Test Automation< /description>             
    < properties>                  
        < java.version>1.8< /java.version>                    
        < slf4j-version>1.7.26< /slf4j-version>                    
        < lombok.version>1.18.2< /lombok.version>                       
        < logback-version>1.2.3< /logback-version>                      
        < assertj.version>3.11.1< /assertj.version>                  
        < jackson.version>2.9.9.3< /jackson.version>                    
        < cucumber.version>4.7.0< /cucumber.version>                 
        < commons.io.version>2.6< /commons.io.version>                   
        < selenium.version>3.141.59< /selenium.version>                   
        < spring.version>5.1.4.RELEASE< /spring.version>                
        < rest.assured.version>4.0.0< /rest.assured.version>                       
    < /properties>                       
    < dependencies>                      
        < dependency>                      
            < groupId>org.springframework.boot< /groupId>                        
            < artifactId>spring-boot-starter< /artifactId>                         
        < /dependency>                

        < dependency>                           
            < groupId>org.springframework.boot< /groupId>                          
            < artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test< /artifactId>                       
            < scope>test< /scope>                             
        < /dependency>              
        
        < !-- dependency injection -->
        < dependency>                               
            < groupId>org.springframework< /groupId>                          
            < artifactId>spring-context< /artifactId>                    
            < /dependency>                 
        
        < !-- cucumber -->
        < dependency>                   
            < groupId>io.cucumber< /groupId>                          
            < artifactId>cucumber-junit< /artifactId>               
            < version>${cucumber.version}< /version>                     
        < /dependency>                     

        < dependency>
            < groupId>io.cucumber< /groupId>                          
            < artifactId>cucumber-java< /artifactId>                   
            < version>${cucumber.version}< /version>                           
        < /dependency>                  

        < dependency>
            < groupId>io.cucumber< /groupId>                     
            < artifactId>cucumber-spring< /artifactId>                  
            < version>${cucumber.version}< /version>                       
        </dependency>                     

        < !--driver-->
        < dependency>
            < groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium< /groupId>                      
            < artifactId>selenium-java< /artifactId>                     
            < version>${selenium.version}< /version>                           
        < /dependency>                         
        
                < !-- Used mainly for FileUtils -->
        < dependency>                              
            < groupId>commons-io< /groupId>                            
            < artifactId>commons-io< /artifactId>                           
            < version>${commons.io.version}< /version>                           
        </dependency>                           

        < !-- assertions -->
        < dependency>
            < groupId>org.assertj< /groupId>                        
            < artifactId>assertj-core< /artifactId>                   
            < version>${assertj.version}< /version>                         
        < /dependency>                        

        < !-- RestAssured -->
        < dependency>                          
            < groupId>io.rest-assured< /groupId>                            
            < artifactId>rest-assured< /artifactId>                            
            < version>${rest.assured.version}< /version>                           
        < /dependency>                              

        < dependency>                                 
            < groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core< /groupId>                          
            < artifactId>jackson-databind< /artifactId>                          
            < version>${jackson.version}< /version>                         
        < /dependency>                         
        
        < !-- logging -->
        < dependency>
            < groupId>org.slf4j< /groupId>                               
            < artifactId>slf4j-api< /artifactId>                  
            < version>${slf4j-version}< /version>                          
        < /dependency>                           

        < dependency>
            < groupId>ch.qos.logback< /groupId>                              
            < artifactId>logback-classic< /artifactId>                          
            < version>${logback-version}< /version>                                 
        < /dependency>                               

        < !-- lombok -->
        < dependency>
            < groupId>org.projectlombok< /groupId>                                    
            < artifactId>lombok< /artifactId>                      
            < version>${lombok.version}< /version>                     
        < /dependency>                         
        
    < /dependencies>                         

    < build>              
        < plugins>                     
            < plugin>                         
                < groupId>org.springframework.boot< /groupId>                         
                < artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin< /artifactId>                       
            < /plugin>                            
        < /plugins>                        
    < /build>                         

< /project>
```

/*************************** Below is my project structure *********************/
My project structure, in stepdefs I have step definition file and hooks file, and ruuners package has test runner file -
src/main/java - com.xx.xx.xx.automation.stepdefs
- com.xx.xx.xx.automation.runners
src/main/resources - features

```
   /****************** Below is my test runner file, When I run, its not executing, not even showing any errors. ****************/
    
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;       
    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;         
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)        
    @CucumberOptions(          
            features = {"classpath:features"},    
            glue = {"com.xx.xx.xx.automation.stepdefs"},        
            tags = {"@SanityTest"},        
            plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber.html","junit:target/cucumber.xml"},    
            monochrome = true,     
            dryRun = false, strict=true)
    
    public class Srt3AppRunner {
    
    }
    
    
    /********* below is my Feature file, I have added tags, but still runner file doesn't run - ***************************************/
    @SanityTest
    Feature: To check the functionality for adding a new Key-list values and to check if able to add same key-list values, verifying the title and add new key for range of values, also to verify the buttons on Add New Key popup
    
    Background: User clicks on Add New Key button on profile dashboard page
    Given user logs in through "Guardian page"
    When user is on profile dashboard page "Global Profile Module"
    Then click on "Add New Key" button
    
    @SanityTest
    Scenario: Click on Add New Key popup to see Add new key, Key description, Checkbox, Add value to key fields and Value type dropdown, Save, Cancel buttons
    And can see "Add new key", "Key description", "Add value to key" fields, "Select a value type" dropdown, and Checkbox "This key has no default value"
    And can see "Add Value" plus button, "Save", "Cancel" buttons
    
    Please help me with this, Thank You
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven Tests Does Not Run Cucumber Scenarios with Spring Boot 2.2 and JUnit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982006/maven-tests-does-not-run-cucumber-scenarios-with-spring-boot-2-2-and-junit-5)

Comment: Yes, its working now, test runner file is executing. 
Thank You M.P.Korstanje, was struggling from this issue from few days.